# Why boost crashes when locale is set std::locale()?

Tags: c++, boost, local

Boost crashes for this code:

```
boost::filesystem::path::imbue(std::locale());
boost::filesystem::path p (L"привет");
```

in "path_traits.hpp":

```
  void dispatch(const std::wstring& c, U& to, const codecvt_type& cvt)
  {
    if (c.size())
      convert(&*c.begin(), &*c.begin() + c.size(), to, cvt); // SIGABRT cvt is invalid
  }
```

Why?
Problem on OSX and Linux

Comment: You may need to generate locale for the lang you use in your code, for ubuntu that is: `sudo locale-gen en_GB en_GB.UTF-8; sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`. Replace en_GB with your lang code.